# Differences between php5 and php5-cli packages on Debian

Tags: php, debian, php5, debian-etch

I have a debian etch server with php5 packages installed.

My issue is that I can't find any php executable to run scripts on the command line. Running "`whereis php5`" return folders with only config files, .so files and no executables and "`whereis php`" returns nothing.

I've googled and found out about php-cli. Is this the solution that I'm looking for? If so, what are the differences between php5 and php5-cli packages? Will installing the php5-cli package interfere with my current setup of php5?

Thanks for the help!

Wadih

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'php5' isn't php itself. There is libapache2-mod-php5 which is the php5 module used by apache (.so file), php5-cli will install a standalone binary file that can be used to run php script locally on the server (/usr/bin/php5).
You can have both installed without any problems

Answer (score 3):

I think the package descriptions says it all :

[php5 package](http://packages.debian.org/etch/php5) description:

> This package is a meta-package that,
>   when installed, guarantees that you
>   have at least one of the four
>   server-side versions of the PHP5
>   interpreter installed. Removing this
>   package won't remove PHP5 from your
>   system, however it may remove other
>   packages that depend on this one.

[php5-cli package](http://packages.debian.org/etch/php5-cli) description:

> This package provides the
>   /usr/bin/php5 command interpreter,
>   useful for testing PHP scripts from a
>   shell, or perhaps even performing
>   general shell scripting tasks, if
>   you're frightened of perl and python.